# Is it possible to tell if a program is running by reading the registry?

Tags: registry

Is there a way to detect if a program is running with Registry and only start another program after the registry has determined that another program is running first.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the registry.  You need process APIs and/or WMI events.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless the program in question writes a specific item to the registry to say it is running, this does not happen automatically.